# What formula should I use to calculate how much space is needed for my moving boxes?

Tags: metric-spaces, algorithms

I have 25 moving boxes filled up with all my belongings. Their dimensions are: 58 x 33 x 42 cm.

I'm trying to determine how much storage space these will require, with a nice formula which I can keep re-calculating when the number of boxes change, or I learn that you can stack fewer/more on top of each other, or other factors.

I sat down and thought about this for a long time, but couldn't figure out a sane way. It seems like it should be pretty simple.

According to my calculations, the cheapest local self-storage unit (3 meters high, 1 meter deep and 1 meter wide) would at best store 21 of my moving boxes. But maybe not, since maybe they cannot be packed so tightly. It's unclear if their stated dimensions are really accurate and if my boxes may "bulge out" slightly, or if they require some kind of "airflow" in between the boxes.

The next "upgrade" in the self-storage place (3 meters high, 2 meters deep and 1,5 meters wide). According to my calculations, it would hold an incredible 84 of my moving boxes, which is way too big and would be a waste of money.

I'm trying to come up with a single formula such as:

```
number_of_square_meters_required = (number_of_boxes something height_of_one_box something width_of_one_box something depth_of_one_box something height_of_room something width_of_room something depth_of_room something empty_buffer_space_between_boxes);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: How do you arrive at $21$? If dimensions were correct (and boxes could be packed tightly), you should be able to stack $5$ levels of $6$ boxes each.

Comment: @Patricio Well, I probably shouldn't even have brought up my calculations, since I'm asking for a way to "automate" this and not have to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

First question: can you turn boxes on the side? In that case you can put 3 boxes in 58x99 cm, 42 cm high, and 3 boxes in 42x99cm, 58 cm high. 7x42=294<300, 5x58=290cm high, so you fit 36 boxes.

Once you have more space, you will have lots of different ways to arrange your boxes more or less effectively. And with my example it’s obvious that the solution doesn’t work at all with a 98x98 room. And it might very well not be optimal with a 289 cm room height. There will not be a single simple formula. You’ll need sn algorithm that tries various possibilities.